# Make a cloned channel in same position as the original

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made nuke command in my discord.js bot, which makes channel with same name, permissions, topic etc, and deletes the "original" channel. But there is one problem, how to make channel in same position as the "original"?

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'nuke',
  aliases: [ 'clearall' ],
  guildOnly: true,
  permissions: [ 'MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS' ],
  clientPermissions: [ 'MANAGE_CHANNELS' ],
  group: 'moderation',
  description: 'Removes all messages in the channel (Deletes the old channel and makes a copy of it with permissions intact)',
  examples: [
    'nuke',
    'clearall'
  ],
  run: async (client, message) => {

    await message.channel.send(`This will remove all conversation in this channel and may cause conflict for bots using ID to track channels. Continue?`);

    const filter = _message => message.author.id === _message.author.id && ['y','n','yes','no'].includes(_message.content.toLowerCase());
    const options = { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] };
    const proceed = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
    .then(collected => ['y','yes'].includes(collected.first().content.toLowerCase()) ? true : false)
    .catch(() => false);

    if (!proceed){
      return message.channel.send(`\\❌ | **${message.author.tag}**, you cancelled the nuke command!`);
    };

    return message.channel.send(`The nuke has been deployed, saying goodbye to **#${message.channel.name}** in 10`)
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => message.channel.clone()
    .then(() => message.channel.delete().catch(() => null)), 10000))
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Channels have a [`position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=position) property so you could set the cloned channel's position to this number using the [`.setPosition()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setPosition) method. You can get the cloned channel after the `.clone()` method is resolved:

```js
return message.channel
  .send(
    `The nuke has been deployed, saying goodbye to **#${message.channel.name}** in 10`,
  )
  .then(() =>
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        message.channel.clone().then((clonedChannel) => {
          const originalPosition = message.channel.position;

          message.channel.delete().catch(() => null);
          clonedChannel.setPosition(originalPosition);
        }),
      10000,
    ),
  );
```