# How can I delete all messages in a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, message

I know about `bulkdelete`, but it can only delete a maximum of 100 messages.

I've tried fetching the messages in the channel and then deleting them. But I get the impression that the bot can't do that if it wasn't active before the messages were sent.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to clone the channel using [TextChannel.clone()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=clone), then delete the original. Additionally, use [.setPosition()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setPosition).

```js
const originalChannel = /* The channel */

try {
   const cloneChannel = await originalChannel.clone();

   await originalChannel.delete();
   await cloneChannel.setPosition(originalChannel.position);
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66930796/12464931

Comment: This [discord support forum discussion](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360033149212-Clear-channel) concurs.